# Paid membership Stripe Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I've been dealing with some errors ive been getting and lately somehow i made it happend but there's a thing i need to add a metadata to my code but dont know where too and how I need your help.

Paid member is being registered but he's not being charge because its being registered without plan.

I guess this is what I need to add `:metadata[plan_id]=2`:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :profile
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      require "stripe"
      Stripe.api_key = "********"

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          :description => email,
          :source => stripe_card_token # obtained with Stripe.js
          )
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end
end






    /* global $*/
/* global Stripe*/
/* global Token*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  // Watch for a form submission:
  $("#form-submit-btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    var error = false;
    var ccNum = $('#card_number').val(),
        cvcNum = $('#card_code').val(),
        expMonth = $('#card_month').val(),
        expYear = $('#card_year').val();

    if (!error) {
      // Get the Stripe token:
      Stripe::Token.create({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear,
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }
    return false;
  }); // form submission

  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    // Get a reference to the form:
    var f = $("#new_user");

    // Get the token from the response:
    var token = response.id;

    // Add the token to the form:
    f.append('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]" value="' + token + '" />');

    // Submit the form:
    f.get(0).submit(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a customer and subscribe them to a plan at the same time, you need to include the `plan` parameter in your [subscription creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription).

In Ruby, it would look like this:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :description => email,
  :source => stripe_card_token, # obtained with Stripe.js
  :plan => "awesome_plan"
)
```

As a side note, customers have an `email` attribute, you may want to put the email in that attribute rather than in `description`. It will let you take advantage of [email receipts](https://support.stripe.com/questions/email-receipts) if you so wish.

Comment: that way its giving me an error

"This customer has no attached payment source"

Comment: Im making two types of Customer Basic(free) and Pro(Paid), so i tried adding ":metadata => ['plan_id': 2]" still not charging

Comment: If you get "This customer has no attached payment source", that means `stripe_card_token` was empty and no source was added to the customer. Double-check that `stripe_card_token` contains the ID of the token that was returned by Stripe.js / Checkout. It should be a string that starts with `"tok_"` followed by random alphanumeric characters.

Comment: i guess the problem is at my JS file but even when im going to steps same as shown in API im still getting an error

Comment: `Stripe::Token.create(
        :card => {
          :number => ccNum,
          :exp_month => expMonth,
          :exp_year => expYear,
          :cvc => cvcNum
        },` This is the correct code from api thats giving me an error **Unexpected token** ???